# Running ":wa" command replaces current search with a return character

Tags: vim

I recently updated to VIM 8.1.49. I'm on a mac for what it matters. This issue never happened before, but it could be tied to another update of plugins.

When I run ":wa" or ":w" to save all opened buffers it almost always clears my current/last search and highlights all the return characters in my files. I'm completely baffled by how to even track this down or where to start looking. I'm not running the command by shortcut, I'm manually entering it.

It doesn't happen 100% of the time and it only happens if there are in fact unsaved buffers. Multiple files being open seems to improve chances of it happened and I have to clear the search highlighting map with ":noh" to make it go away.

EDIT:
Here is a link to my VIM config: https://github.com/RussBrown00/902LabsDotFiles/tree/master/vim

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking a minimal, complete, verifiable example makes it hard to answer.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) At least post [a link to] your `~/.vimrc` so that we can look for clues.

Comment: Updated original post with a link to my dot files. I can't verify it myself because it's not even reproducible in a consistent way that I can find/understand yet.

Comment: I'm positively sure it's hidden in `autocmd BufWrite,FileWritePre * call RemoveWhiteSpace()` in `vimrc_autocmds`.

Comment: I've had that command in there for a couple years now at least, but it makes sense. It's just looking at all the buffers from files to the search command. I wonder if the latest VIM made a change that resulted in this buffer getting scrubbed where before it didn't... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) I checked to see if my RemoveWhiteSpace was the culprit and I was really sure it was. However after making some changes to the below command, the issue did in fact pop back up.

```
autocmd BufWrite,FileWritePre * call RemoveWhiteSpace()
```

The real issue it turned out is a bug/issue with vim-prettier. I removed the plugin and my issues went away. I didn't bother to debug it further.